# Why decrement front and rear by 1 when deleting only node in circular queue?

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, queue

For context, I am doing a Data Structures and Algorithms course. The context of this is queue implementation of array:

Instructor says when we delete the first node from a circular queue, we increment front by 1. (Makes perfect sense)

Instructor shows a table of conditions for "empty queue" and "full queue". Both columns contain the conditions:
  front = rear + 1;
  (front = 0) && (rear = arraySize - 1);

Instructor says to clear this up, instead of incrementing front when we delete a node, we will decrement both front and rear by 1.

Then the table of example queues magically fixes itself and we move on to the new conditions for "empty queue" and "full queue".

Could someone please help me understand this? Because two -1's doesn't = a +1... I'm fairly new to this subject but I have learned the Tortoise and the Hare, and I was wondering if there was some similar rule/algorithm/whatever that could clear this up?
(I did try both Google searching this and searching SO before I asked but I may not be using the correct terminology in my queries.)
Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have some sample code you could add as an edit that might help illustrate your question?

Comment: did you miss some modular like front = (rear+1)%arraySize?

Comment: `queue implementation of array` - strange, it would seem more common to have a _queue_ implementation _using_ an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question it would be good to picture how the queue in array look like.

In following code I will use `int qh` as queue head and `int qt` as queue tail. `arrayQ` is a boolean array which show if there is an element on a i-position.

Let's assume that there are some dynamic changes to our array. customerCome() adds an element in queue and customerLeave() decrease queue by 1.

```
bool[] arrayQ = new bool[256];
int qh = 0; int qt = 0;
arrayQ[qt++] = true;
while(qh != qt){
  if(customerCome())
     arrayQ[qt++] = true;
  if(customerLeave()){
     arrayQ[qh++] = false;
  }
}
```

Now if we use this code as is, when customer leaves we will always have first elements(from 0 to qh) as false and just hold not necessary values. As I understood your instructor said not only decrement POINTERS(qh and qt) by 1, but also move entire array by 1 element back.(1st element becomes 0st, 2nd becomes 1st)

This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKqPl.png) represents how you move entire queue. Note that if we don't make 2-3 step, 1st element will always remain false and just keep your memory.

Don't know if that's what your instructor meant, but I hope this will help